# AG-Grid Single Selection Within RowGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I was wondering if it was possible to replicate AG-Grids's single selection within a rowGroup?

For example, If I had multiple rows within a group that are selectable, I want to be able to select a row within that group and have it automatically deselect the previously selected row. Mimicking the single selection.

[image]

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is something inbuilt (would be ideal) but you could achieve it programmatically by deselecting other siblings on rowSelection event:

```
onRowSelected = event => {
  if (event.node.selected) {
    event.node.parent.childrenAfterFilter
      .filter(childNode => childNode.id !== event.node.id)
      .forEach(node => node.setSelected(false));
  }
}
```

Comment: @ShawnT please accept the answer if it solved the problem :)

Comment: Oh my bad! I'm sorta new to SO